# Is it safe to connect an M.2 SATA SSD (via USB 3.0 adapter) from a hacked Windows computer to a Mac?

Tags: firmware

As long as the Mac doesn't try to open any potentially harmful files on the drive, what's the worst that could happen? Could a firmware hack happen?

Answer (score 1):

First check if any launch agents or daemons are enabled which may try to access the USB storage when detecting a new device is connected. Also, use using launchctl to view and disable any automatically run programs which may be accessing the USB storage.

Since there have been instance of cross-platform malaware (e.g. some of whom have used Java), its best to remain cautious.

I would recommend installing an anti-virus/anti-malaware temporarily on the mac for precaution, before connecting the drive.